# How do I reuse single model field validators for forms without using ModelForm?

Tags: django, python-3.x

How can I reuse model field validators when creating a form. I can't use ModelForm because the form only uses part of the model's fields and I also have additional form fields.

## Minimal example

I have a model for an (encryption) key that is always 32 characters in length and I want to use this restriction in the model and forms that accept that key.

**models.py**

```
class EncryptionKey(models.Model)
    key = models.CharField("Encryption Key", max_length=32, validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(32)])
```

**forms.py**

```
class NewUserForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', required=True, max_length=256)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', required=True, max_length=256)
    key = # How do I reuse the key from the model here?
```

I am looking for a idiomatic way to do this in Django 2.1.

*I spend >20 minutes googling for this but all I find is how to use ModelForm.*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is idiomatic or not but you can use `fields_for_model` helper from `django.forms.models`:

```
from django.forms.models import fields_for_model

from yourapp.models import EncryptionKey


class NewUserForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First Name', required=True, max_length=256)
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', required=True, max_length=256)
    key = fields_for_model(EncryptionKey, ['key'])['key']
```

I am not even sure if that is documented.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the "canonical" answer in the [Django docs for Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) (emphasis mine):

> ## Abstract base classes
>
> Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common
>   information into a number of other models. You write your base class
>   and put `abstract=True` in the Meta class. This model will then not be
>   used to create any database table. Instead, when it is used as a base
>   class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child
>   class.
>
> An example:
>
> ```
> from django.db import models
>
> class CommonInfo(models.Model):
>     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
>     age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
>
>     class Meta:
>         abstract = True
>
> class Student(CommonInfo):
>     home_group = models.CharField(max_length=5)
> ```
>
> The Student model will have three fields: `name`, `age` and `home_group`.
>   The `CommonInfo` model cannot be used as a normal Django model, since it
>   is an abstract base class. It does not generate a database table or
>   have a manager, and cannot be instantiated or saved directly.
>
> Fields inherited from abstract base classes can be overridden with
>   another field or value, or be removed with `None`.
>
> **For many uses, this type of model inheritance will be exactly what you**
>   **want. It provides a way to factor out common information at the Python**
>   **level**, while still only creating one database table per child model at
>   the database level.

The only downside I can see with this, is that inheritance is used for "has-a" relations and not "is-a". Following the above example: A Student is modelled as being a specialization of common info but obviously isn't.